# Travelling to London with EU refugee's passport

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, austria, refugees

I want to travel to London with Austrian refugee's passport, is it possible?
Do I need a visa?

Comment: You're leaving from Austria I presume ?

Comment: yes I am leaving from Austria.

Answer (score 14):

[The UK requires visas](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/stateless-or-refugee/tourism) of all refugee travel document holders, [unless the UK issued the travel document](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=GB&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=VS&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C) (in which case it is obviously good for return to the UK).